# How to repeat a process by calling a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation

I recently proposed this simple feature in a previous post by using prompt() to acquire user inputs.  Since then, I have elevated myself to use HTML form inputs to reach a similar result.  I am unable to get the equation to refresh.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Simply...

-Random generate two numbers between 1-10...*works only once*

-User inputs an answer and compare...*works*

-Tally total answers and correct answers...*works*

-Provide a number grade...*works*

The math generation "getMath()" does not re-run at the end of the "result()" and I am not sure why.

Please feel free to beat me up on syntax.

Moving forward, I will be adding digits and changing the operation to incrementally increase the difficulty level.  But one step at a time.

Thank you in advance for your time and insight.

```js
var correct = 0,
  wrong = 0,
  ans,
  firstnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1),
  secondnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1),
  total = firstnum + secondnum,
  score,
  input,
  calc = "+";

function getMath() {

  document.getElementById("firstnum").value = firstnum;
  document.getElementById("secondnum").value = secondnum;
  document.getElementById("calc").value = calc;
}

function getAnswer() {

  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  if (input == total) {
    correct++;
  } else {
    wrong++;
  }
  result();
}


function result() {

  score = correct + wrong;
  percent = correct / score;
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
  document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = correct;
  document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = percent * 100;
  getMath();
}
```

```html
<body onload="getMath()">

  <h1>Math Test</h1>

  <input type="text" id="firstnum"></input>
  <input type="text" id="calc">
  <input type="text" id="secondnum">
  <hr>

  <form id="form1" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="" size="10">
    <button onclick="getAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
  </form>

  <p>Total Answered</p>
  <p id="score"></p>
  <p>Answered Correctly</p>
  <p id="ans"></p>
  <p>Your number grade</p>
  <p id="percent">%</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is placing a function at the end of *result()* not valid?

Comment: `The math generation "getMath()" does not re-run at the end of the "result()" and I am not sure why.` It looks like it is running once on load, and once again after submitting an answer.

Comment: Do you want to rerun `getmath()` when any of the values in `firstnum`, `secondnum` or `calc` are changed?

Comment: After calculating the user input and true/false, I want to generate a new set of numbers to calculate another user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second call to `getMath` runs, but it makes no difference on the page. That function does not pick new random values, but just redisplays what was already there... those random values were only generated once when the script loaded.

So move that randomising logic inside `getMath`. Also try to avoid too many global variables. If you would assign a new click handler to your button each time you generate a new math challenge, then you can in fact pass all necessary variables around and keep all the rest declared as local variables. Remove the `onclick` from the HTML part, and use code to set `onclick`.

Also change the `input` elements to `span` elements when the user is not supposed to change their content.

Here is how it could work:

```js
window.onload = () => getMath(0, 0);

function getMath(correct, wrong) {
    var firstnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1),
        secondnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1),
        calc = "+",
        total = firstnum+secondnum;
    document.getElementById("firstnum").textContent = firstnum;
    document.getElementById("secondnum").textContent = secondnum;
    document.getElementById("calc").textContent = calc;
    document.getElementById("userInput").value = "";
    document.getElementById("btnAnswer").onclick = () => getAnswer(total, correct || 0, wrong || 0);
}

function getAnswer(total, correct, wrong){
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    if (input == total){
        correct++;
    } else{
        wrong++;
    }
    result(correct, wrong);
}


function result(correct, wrong){
    var score = correct+wrong;
    var percent = correct/score;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = correct;
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = percent*100;
    getMath(correct, wrong);
}
```

```html
<h1>Math Test</h1>

<span id="firstnum"> </span>
<span id="calc"> </span>
<span id="secondnum"> </span>
<hr>

<form id="form1" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="" size="10">
    <button id="btnAnswer">Submit Answer</button>
</form>

<p>Total Answered: <span id="score"></span></p>
<p>Answered Correctly: <span id="ans"></span></p>
<p>Your number grade: <span id="percent">%</span></p>
```

Comment: I see that it works, But,  I am trying to understand the syntax on the button function.  I cant seem to connect the dots. I see the "for" loop but do not understand the target.

Comment: The  button function is written as [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), the `()` is the function's empty  argument list. You can also write it as a an inline `function`. What you prefer. There is no `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.  Your additions are quite effective.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you weren't getting a second round of numbers is because **the code that generates the random numbers wasn't inside of the `getMath()` function**. The random number code only ran once, when the page first loads.

Now besides that, you have a lot of redundant/unneeded code (i.e. there is no need to keep track of how many wrong answers there are as long as we know how many questions were asked and how many you got correct) as well as many of your variables have names that don't accurately express what they contain.

Cleaning it all up, reduces the amount of code and the complexity of it as well.

See the inline comments for what changes were made:

```js
// Do all your event binding in JavaScript, not with inline HTML event attributes:
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", populate);
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", result);

// Declare and initialize all your variables.
var correct = 0;
var numQuestions = null;
var total = null;
var calc = "+";

// Get your DOM references just once and set your variable
// to the element itself, not a property of the element so 
// that if you ever want to get a different property, you
// already have the DOM reference.
var firstNumElement = document.getElementById("firstnum");
var secondNumElement = document.getElementById("secondnum");
var calcElement = document.getElementById("calc");
var input = document.getElementById("userInput")
var numCorrectElement = document.getElementById("score");
var numQuestionsElement =  document.getElementById("ans");
var percentElement = document.getElementById("percent");

function populate() {
  // You need to generate new randoms after each successful guess
  // so these lines need to be in a function that will be called again 
  firstNumElement.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  secondNumElement.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  calcElement.textContent = calc;
  // prepending a "+" in front of the textContent converts it to a number
  total = +firstNumElement.textContent + +secondNumElement.textContent;
  numQuestions++;  // Update how many questions have been asked
  input.value = ""; // reset the user input
}

function result(){
  // The getAnswer function should just be part of this function.
  // We have a simple if/then here, so the JavaScript ternary syntax is easier:
  correct = input.value == total ? correct + 1 : correct;

  // Only use .innerHTML when the string has HTML in it that needs to be parsed.
  // If not, use .textContent - it's faster and safer.
  numCorrectElement.textContent = correct;
  numQuestionsElement.textContent = numQuestions;
  percentElement.textContent = (correct / numQuestions * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
  populate();  // Generate new randoms and update the page
}
```

```html
<h1>Math Test</h1>

<!-- 
  input elements don't have a closing tag
  also, use type=number for numeric input
  But here, since users won't be interacting 
  with this data, don't even use form fields.
-->
<span id="firstnum"></span>
<span type="text" id="calc"></span>
<span type="number" id="secondnum"></span>
<hr>

<!-- You're not submitting data anywhere, so you don't need a form element -->
<input type="number" id="userInput" size="10">
<button type="button">Submit Answer</button>

<p>Total Questions: <span id="ans"></span></p>
<p>Answered Correctly: <span id="score"></span></p>
<p>Your number grade: <span id="percent"></span></p>
```

Comment: An abundance of useful tips.  Thank you.